# shortening the code JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I needed to help shorten this code. My project contains this section 32x. So I want to ask if someone does not know how to simplify and generalize it.

```
conn[1] = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn[1].prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM nfl.minnesota");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            teamA = rs.getInt("MinnvsAt");
            teamB = rs.getInt("AtvsMinn");
            ID = rs.getBoolean("MinnvsAtP");
            placement();
            place();
        }
        PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn[1].prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(MinnvsAt) FROM nfl.minnesota WHERE MinnvsAtP = TRUE");
        ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();
        rs1.next();
        int SUMPointsAH = rs1.getInt(1);

        PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn[1].prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(MinnvsAt) FROM nfl.minnesota WHERE MinnvsAtP = FALSE");
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
        rs2.next();
        int SUMPointsAA = rs2.getInt(1);

        PreparedStatement stmt3 = conn[1].prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(AtvsMinn) FROM nfl.minnesota WHERE MinnvsAtP = TRUE");
        ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery();
        rs3.next();
        int SUMPointsBH = rs3.getInt(1);

        PreparedStatement stmt4 = conn[1].prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(AtvsMinn) FROM nfl.minnesota WHERE MinnvsAtP = FALSE");
        ResultSet rs4 = stmt4.executeQuery();
        rs4.next();
        int SUMPointsBA = rs4.getInt(1);
        pointsH.add(SUMPointsAA);

    }
```

Comment: You may want to look into SQL `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your 4 queries, 2 queries with some parameters and extract two helper methods to be more DRY but overall to make your code more robust and readable because your declare too many variables that besides have a too broad scope.
You could write something like :

```
public int executeMinnvsAtPQuery(String MinnvsAtP){
        String query = "SELECT SUM(MinnvsAt) FROM nfl.minnesota WHERE MinnvsAtP = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn[1].prepareStatement(minnvsAtPQuery);
        stmt.setString(1, MinnvsAtP);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        return rs.getInt(1);
}

public int executeAtvsMinnQuery(String AtvsMinn){
        String query = "SELECT SUM(AtvsMinn) FROM nfl.minnesota WHERE MinnvsAtP = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn[1].prepareStatement(minnvsAtPQuery);
        stmt.setString(1, AtvsMinn);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        return rs.getInt(1);
}
```

And use them in this way :

```
int SUMPointsAH = executeMinnvsAtPQuery("TRUE");
int SUMPointsAA =  executeMinnvsAtPQuery("FALSE");

int SUMPointsBH  = executeAtvsMinnQuery("TRUE");
int SUMPointsBA =  executeAtvsMinnQuery("FALSE");
```

Note that the even if the two queries are very close, I don't think that you can make the `sum(...)` aggregate a parameter valuable by `PreparedStatement`.
And I would not recommend concatenation of SQL parts that is both error prone and not safe.

> My project contains this section 32x.

To reduce this one to 1X, you could follow the same logic and extract the set of these queries in a method with some parameters that you may invoke anywhere then.

Note also that queries execution may have a cost in terms of execution time. So you should also ensure that your queries are optimized and required.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can cut the actual number of queries executed in half by retrieving both columns at the same time.
2. You can supply TRUE or FALSE via a parameter.

   So the only `PreparedStatement` you need is `SELECT SUM(MinnvsAt), SUM(AtvsMinn) FROM nfl.minnesota WHERE MinnvsAtP = ?`.

   So you can cut the whole thing in more than half.
3. As noted by @GriffeyDog, you can do the whole thing in one query, via `GROUP BY`:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(MinnvsAt), SUM(AtvsMinn) FROM nfl.minnesota GROUP BY MinnvsAtP  ORDER BY MinnvsAtP
   ```

   So the first row will be the FALSE results and the second row will be the TRUE results, and the first column of each will be `SUM(MinnvsAt)` and the second `SUM(AtvsMinn)`.

   So only one `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` needs to be executed.